# htacess rule for 301 redirect with query string with predefined rule

Tags: .htaccess

Here is the format of my url

www.mysite.com/display/search/?cat=1&type=band&city=%20cityname

i want to redirect it to

www.mysite.com/display/search/?cat=1&type=band&city=cityname

i.e by removing only space from the city. Please note /display/search already refer rule for modules/display/search.php

Comment: Do you want to redirect because an error happens or to trim the string? Trimming the string in the application seems less painful. Or even better, fix it in the link

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note that this rule must be after the rewrite from `search` to `search.php`):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} city=%20([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^display/search\.php$ $0?city=%1 [R]
```